# Zooming with keyboard shortcuts doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just upgraded Ubuntu to the 14.04 version on my laptop.
Before (Saucy salamander) I had no problems in zooming for example pdf files (using say Evince) with keyboard shortcuts, namely I used always Ctrl++ and Ctrl+- and I never had problems.

After the update it happened something strange.
The Ctrl+- was still working, but Ctrl++ was not! I checked the keyboard settings, they were not corresponding to the above commands, so I changed them and now even the zoom out shortcut is not working. I don't really understand where the problem is.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If you need to zoom-in the shortcut has changed from Ctrl++ to Ctrl+Shift++. In other words you're pressing Ctrl+= instead of Ctrl++ and you need to hold shift to use Ctrl++. I hope that's not to confusing of a response.